# Math Functions both TeX and Infix Notation

Tags: math-mode, pstricks

I am trying to automate plotting graphs of mathematical functions. For that I need infix (or RPN) notation. I also want to annotate the output automatically with the correct mathmode of TeX.

For example I want to generate

```
sin(x)          % infix (in Radian)
x RadtoDeg sin  % RPN   (in degree)
\sin(x)         % TeX   (no conversion, just display)
```

in one go from one source. As a source I am willing to accept any of the three (or even a fourth notation if necessary).

A solution should be able to handle `pi` and `Euler`.

---

There is the `infixtoRPN` package that does half of what I want, but does not produce TeX output as far as I know.

---

Using another programming language might be possible as well. It's just that I don't know where to start.

---

Comment: why just rad in the middle one? why not assume the same definition of sin in all three syntax?

Comment: What would be beneficial is to provide a minimal use case so community members interested in answering the question can figure out what your input would look like, as well as the expected output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because for some reason the definitions do not coincide: infix `sin(x)` assumes radian, but RPN `x sin` assumes degrees. At least in `pstricks`.

Comment: you didn't mention pstricks until this comment

Comment: Why can't you use the infix notation for all PSTricks macros?

Comment: It seems I am using an outdated version of `pst-func` and its `pstcumintegral` fails with infix. Anyway, having a converter for infix <--> TeX code will be good enough.